# What are some causes of unmodified .cpp files recompiling each time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have some unmodified .cpp files of mine that are compiling each time, which is slowing down my compile time. Since these are not modified, and am using #pragma once in Visual Studio 2017, I don't see why they are still re-compiling.

What are some causes of unmodified .cpp files recompiling each time?

Comment: `#pragma once` does not prevent files being re-compiled. There is something else wrong with your project and/or code. You are not by any chance `#include`ing C++ source files?

Comment: If headers included by that file are modified, then the file needs to be recompiled.

Comment: A .h file that they #include changing.  Or a missing project database.  Or file(s) having a bad time stamp, making them always newer than the generated .obj file.  Change the build verbosity to Detailed so you can see why.  Search the trace for "will be compiled because".  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run.

Comment: @HansPassant I always get the same 5 files compiling (part of my own library). After doing those, I found this: "X.cpp will be compiled because X.H was modified at 6/23/2018 8:58:49 AM." I never modified the file prior to build.

Comment: Well, *something* did, it was not me.  Make the file read-only and that something is liable to go kapooey.

Comment: It seemed to have ignored the .h/.cpp files were readonly and compiled them anyway. Here's the detailed info: One of the file groups it's compiling is Vector2D.cpp/.h. It compiles this when I made a modification in another class of the same namespace, but different files. Each .h file has #include "common.h", which in turn includes an #include of both Vector2D.cpp/.h and the .cpp/.h that I modified. Each header uses #pragma once.

Comment: Precompiled headers.  If any header in the list of precompiled headers changes, all the source files including the precompiled header must be rebuilt.  Precompiled headers are only advantageous for huge projects.

Comment: Weird thing is when I changed my Array.h's includes to just including iostream instead of common.h, and then modify Array.h, it still compiles Vector2D.h, etc. It may be due to other files perhaps. I agree, I might just get rid of any precompiled headers and try that.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be working now. I got rid of common.h, and put the includes as needed in each .cpp/.h file. I don't see any extra files being compiled now, and it takes about 2 seconds to compile with one modified file instead of 6+ seconds now.

Comment: Precompiled headers work best for external libraries, specially heavily templated ones; instead of your own.